# Set additional information in highcharts tooltip

Tags: highcharts

Im doing a columnrange highchart, my json sample data is as below:

```
{
    "name": "PW (md.h24mi)",
        "data": [
        [320, 320.06],
        [319.05, 319.1],
        [319.05, 319.1],
        [319.05, 319.1],
        [319.05, 319.1],
        [319.05, 319.1],
        [319.05, 319.1],
        [319.05, 319.1],
        [319.05, 319.1],
        [319.05, 319.1],
        [319.05, 319.1],
        [320, 320.04]
    ],
        "PW": [
        ["PW0000025090"],
        ["PW0000025158"],
        ["PW0000025160"],
        ["PW0000025171"],
        ["PW0000025172"],
        ["PW0000025161"],
        ["PW0000025173"],
        ["PW0000025159"],
        ["PW0000025164"],
        ["PW0000025170"],
        ["PW0000024827"],
        ["PW0000024461"]
    ],
        "GROUP": [
        ["IT"],
        ["Sierra"],
        ["Sierra"],
        ["RF Engineers"],
        ["RF Engineers"],
        ["Sierra"],
        ["RF Engineers"],
        ["Sierra"],
        ["RF Engineers"],
        ["RF Engineers"],
        ["Sierra"],
        ["IP"]
    ],
        "worksum": [
        ["Call Back Assist (CBA) Modification"],
        ["TMA Installation"],
        ["TMA Installation"],
        ["TMA Installation"],
        ["TMA Installation"],
        ["TMA Installation"],
        ["TMA Installation"],
        ["TMA Installation"],
        ["TMA Installation"],
        ["TMA Installation"],
        ["TMA Installation"],
        ["Upgrade Consumer Wimax Firewall Modules to R77.10"]
    ]
}
```

How do i get it to show the "PW" and "worksum" in the tooltip? I've tried the code below but nada.

```
    tooltip: {
           formatter: function() {
    var point = this.points[0];
    return '<b>'+ point.x +'<br />'
        +point.PW + '<br />'
        +point.worksum + '<br />'
        +'</b><br />Duration:'+ point.series.data[0].low +' - '+ point.series.data[0].high;
},
shared: true

           }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set PW and worksum in series, so you have access in tooltip via `point.series.options.PW/worksum`. Then you need to extract corresponding value (use `this.x`). And that's all: http://jsfiddle.net/HsWF2/119/

```
   tooltip: {
       formatter: function () {
           var point = this.points[0],
               series = point.series,
               PW = series.options.PW[point.x],
               worksum = series.options.worksum[point.x];
           return '<b>' + point.x + '<br />' + PW + '<br />' + worksum + '<br />' + '</b><br />Duration:' + point.series.data[0].low + ' - ' + point.series.data[0].high;
       },
       shared: true

   },
```